# microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine 64 bit

Tags: c#, oledb, 32bit-64bit, provider, jet

I am getting error while connect to data with oledb provider in my Project.

```
connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +"filepath.mdb";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        return "Success";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return ex.Message;
                }
```

tried this code in console application then its working fine. 
But in my project source this provider not working. getting exception on  `*The 'Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0' Provider is not registered in the local machine*`

working in my project also when  i changing access engine instead of jet.

Why jet provider working on separate source. not my project source?

Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

The 64-bit version of `Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0` doesn't exists so you have to compile your project for `x86`.

Comment: I changed x86 instead of Any cpu. But my dll file not working. it gives belo error.

Uncaught System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly

How to resolve this?

Comment: give a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=System.BadImageFormatException

can you recompile your dll as 32bit?